# How to vectorize this code below in Python without joining two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, apply

I have two dataframes with multiple columns like below

head(df

```
    SCHEDULING_DC_NBR       COMMODITY_CODE          Unload_Start_Time   DOW     Dlry
0   6042.0                    SCGR                      15:15           SUN      5
1   6042.0                    SCGR                      15:30           SUN      6
2   6042.0                    SCGR                      15:45           SUN      7
3   6042.0                    SCGR                      16:15           SUN      8
4   6042.0                    SCGR                      18:30           SUN      9
```

head(config_df)

```
Node      Window               APPLICABLE_DAYS   COMMODITY_CODE  Window_start_time  config_ID
7023.0  03:15 AM to 03:16 AM            MON         SCPR                03:15        123
7023.0  03:15 AM to 03:16 AM            THUR        SCPR                03:15        123
7023.0  03:15 AM to 03:16 AM            FRI         SCPR                03:15        123
6042.0  06:00 PM to 06:05 PM            SUN         SCPR                18:00        111
6042.0  03:00 PM to 03:05 PM            SUN         SCGR                15:00        222
```

I want to apply row-wise operation on **dataframe df** to find the appropriate **capacity_config_id** from config_df using some logic like below using apply function.

```
def config_map(row):
    row = row.copy()
    return config_df.loc[(config_df['Node'] == row['SCHEDULING_DC_NBR']) & (config_df['COMMODITY_CODE'] == row['COMMODITY_CODE']) 
                          &  (config_df['APPLICABLE_DAYS'].str.contains(row['DOW'],case=False))
                          & (live_config['Window_start_time'] == row['Unload_Start_Time']),"capacity_config_id"].values[0]
```

Even though, the above code works it takes a lot of time to run.
I don't want to join or merge both the dataframes, as i will be doing multiple other checks in apply function above. I am looking for a way to vectorize this function for faster computation.

Comment: please fix the typos in your code.  verify that it runs before pasting, please

Comment: sounds like a `merge`

Comment: @anon01 Sorry for the typos. Fixed the typos in the code

Comment: @QuangHoang I know we can merge, but i am looking for other options as my original config_map function contains multiple computations and conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Pandas apply method, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html
Using this you can vectorize the operation